# Select files and color them in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I would like to achieve something similar to the coloring of modified files by VS Code. 
I want to pick files manually and color them. Is it possible in VS Code or some extension?

Comment: the extension API does not allow this, you have to write your own WebviewView with a file tree

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My goal was to access manually picked files quickly; I used the File Focus extension.